# Can I use message selectors in OpenMQ UMS?

Tags: java, openmq

I'm accessing OpenMQ from Delphi using UMS. This all works fine but I need to be able to filter the messages when reading them from a queue. Normally I would use a message selector but I can't see if UMS exposes this functionality. Anyone know if it does?

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be ... no.